# Django app: Heroku app crashes after switching to daphne

Tags: python, django, heroku, chat, asgi

I was having a lot of issues getting websockets working for a chat app I'm building in Django on Heroku. Most of the stackoverflow posts use daphne instead of gunicorn in their Procfile, so I recently switched to using daphne. **First question: Does anyone know if I really do need to be using daphne? Or is there a way to get websockets to work on Heroku using gunicorn?**

Since switching to daphne, my app is working on my local web server, but when i push to heroku, my app crashes and I get this error:

`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

I've tried many solutions proposed on similar stackoverflow questions, but none of them work. It seems that it likely has to do with my Settings.py, Procfile or asgi.py files.

**asgi.py**

```
# mysite/asgi.py
import os
import django
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter, get_default_application
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")
django.setup()

# startapp = get_default_application() #todo: confirm why app doesn't crash if this is commented out... this is called from Procfile

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({ #
  "http": get_asgi_application(), # TODO: CONFIRM http vs https
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**Procfile**

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne django_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python3 manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
```

**settings.py**

```
import django
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import os
import django_heroku

# setup(needed for daphne)
SECRET_KEY = 'seckey...' #todo: test removing this in own deployment
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")
# application = get_wsgi_application()


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
#SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = 'True'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition
# Allows Django to look for models (for Databases)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig', #allows Django to correctly search your templates for the 'blog' app
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'chat',
    'channels',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django_messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # 'libraries': {
            #     'staticfiles':'chat.templatetags.__init__.py'
            # }
        },
    },
]

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) ,'../templates').replace('\\','/')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'blog/templates'), # Django will look at the templates from templates/ directory under your project
)

# ~~~MESSAGES CONFIG~~~
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.asgi.application' # older version of django: 'django_project.routing.application'

# Channels redis config:
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            #"hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)], or 'redis' #l ocal
            "hosts": ['rediss://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25180'], # REDIS_TLS_URL #todo: confirm. Changed from "127.0.0.1" to 'redis'... found promising answer, changing this
            # 'redis://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25179' REDIS_URL
        },
        "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns", #todo: add "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns",
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL'),
         "OPTIONS": {
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {
                "ssl_cert_reqs": False
            }
        }
    }
}



# Use Postgrest Database in Shrouded-Inlet
DB_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DATABASE_URL = DB_URL


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


django_heroku.settings(locals())

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 4000
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfilescustom') #todo: may have to add own staticFileDir folder
]
```

**Heroku Logs:**

```
"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191111+00:00 app[web.1]: class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191120+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191258+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191417+00:00 app[web.1]: self.check_apps_ready()
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191418+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191540+00:00 app[web.1]: settings.INSTALLED_APPS
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191540+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191668+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191669+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191796+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191797+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191927+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.191928+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192056+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192057+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./django_project/settings.py", line 204, in <module>
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192203+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup()
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192203+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192317+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192318+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192433+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config.import_models()
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192434+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192592+00:00 app[web.1]: self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192593+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192717+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192718+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192815+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.192819+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
    2021-03-24T00:09:27.937262+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.877569+00:00 app[worker.1]: Running worker for channels ['channel_layer']
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.950161+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.951479+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.952190+00:00 app[worker.1]: execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.952266+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.952874+00:00 app[worker.1]: utility.execute()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.952963+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.953514+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.953607+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.954188+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.954413+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.954896+00:00 app[worker.1]: output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.955486+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runworker.py", line 46, in handle
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.955801+00:00 app[worker.1]: worker.run()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.956071+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/server.py", line 62, in run
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.956383+00:00 app[worker.1]: event_loop.run_until_complete(self.handle())
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.956455+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.957118+00:00 app[worker.1]: return future.result()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.957514+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 30, in handle
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.957810+00:00 app[worker.1]: [listener.result() for listener in listeners]
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.958233+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.959151+00:00 app[worker.1]: [listener.result() for listener in listeners]
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.959234+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 37, in listener
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.959589+00:00 app[worker.1]: message = await self.channel_layer.receive(channel)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.959659+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 501, in receive
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.960387+00:00 app[worker.1]: return (await self.receive_single(channel))[1]
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.960664+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 524, in receive_single
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.961154+00:00 app[worker.1]: index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.961341+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 356, in _brpop_with_clean
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.961891+00:00 app[worker.1]: async with self.connection(index) as connection:
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.962103+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 884, in __aenter__
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.963869+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.963943+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 80, in pop
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.964279+00:00 app[worker.1]: conn = await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.964342+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 175, in create_redis
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.964727+00:00 app[worker.1]: loop=loop)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.964806+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 113, in create_connection
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.965216+00:00 app[worker.1]: timeout)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.965286+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.965790+00:00 app[worker.1]: return (yield from fut)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.965850+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 24, in open_connection
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.966201+00:00 app[worker.1]: lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.966271+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 824, in create_connection
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.967044+00:00 app[worker.1]: sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.967368+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 850, in _create_connection_transport
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.968101+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from waiter
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.968459+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 505, in data_received
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.969699+00:00 app[worker.1]: ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.969776+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 201, in feed_ssldata
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.970144+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.970216+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.971002+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    2021-03-24T00:09:32.971118+00:00 app[worker.1]: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
    2021-03-24T00:09:33.408193+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```